# SSL CONECTION ERROR. Erro de conexão c# com MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, banco-de-dados

minha string de conexao com o banco:

```
`public MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Persist Security Info = false; server = localhost; database = infoelectra; uid = root; pwd =");`
```

O meu erro está na hora de inserir dados na tabela, da um erro de SSL CONNECTION ERROR.
[Erro que aparece ao tentar inserir dados](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJFIa.jpg)
meu código para as informações do formulário sejam inseridas no banco:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string nome, email, telefone, celular;
            nome = txt_nome.Text;
            email = txt_email.Text;
            telefone = txt_telefone.Text;
            celular = txt_celular.Text;
           
            if (txt_nome.Text == "" ||  txt_email.Text== "" || txt_celular.Text == "" )
            {
                MessageBox.Show("PREENCHA TODOS OS CAMPOS OBRIGATÓRIOS(*)!","ATENÇÃO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                txt_nome.Focus();
    
            }
            else
            {
                conexao con = new conexao(); //novo objeto da classe de conexão 
                
                try
                {
                    con.conectar();
                    label8.Text = "CONEÇÃO OK";
                    string sql = "insert into cadastro values (null, @Nome, @Telefone, @Celular, @Email, @Data_nasc";
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con.conn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", txt_nome.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefone", txt_telefone.Text );
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@celular", txt_celular.Text );
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txt_email.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Data_nasc", txt_data.Text);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    
                    MessageBox.Show("Usuaro cadastrado com sucesso!", "CADASTRO EFETUADO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    
                    txt_nome.Clear();
                    txt_telefone.Clear();
                    txt_celular.Clear();
                    txt_email.Clear();
                    txt_nome.Focus();
                }
    
                catch (Exception E)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(E.Message.ToString(), "ERRO", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
    
                con.desconectar();
            }
    
            
    
        }
```

Comment: olá, sugiro da uma olhada nesse site e testar com uma string de conexão de lá: https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/  esses espaços na sua string, não sei se isso é bem aceito tbm

Comment: @RicardoPontual coloquei a conexão padrão deste site, ainda está dando o mesmo erro... :/

Comment: @srTeixeiraDias Tem certeza de que o erro é só no Insert?

Comment: corrigi aqui... Obrigado

Answer (score -2):

Consegui resolver

troquei a minha string de conexão, e desabilitei o SSL no meu SGBD, editando a conexão e indo na aba SSL, no campo Use SSL deixei desabilitado.

e essa foi a minha string de conexão:

```
public MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=infoelectra;Uid=root;Pwd=;SslMode=none;");
```